# i cannot open explorer in document library in share point .i have error

Tags: open-with-explorer

hello i use share point 2013 when i do open with explorer in document library  have error what i do. i have full permission in share point and i have error only in 1 document library . other document library i can open with explorers
i cheking setting my browser and my servis clinet in my computer. do not okey
with this problam. pllzz hellp mee tanks

my error 
\my domain\DavWWWRoot\RTIS\DBS\SYS\Drawing is not accessible. you might not have permission access permissions

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following things to troubleshoot this issue:

1. Try to add the path to Trust sites in Internet Explorer.
2. Enable “Automatic logon with current user name and password” option. Internet options > Security > Custom level > User Authentication.

Here is a blog has some troubleshooting steps for this issue, which could be useful to you:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/mapping-sharepoint-document-libraries-without-getting-nik-d-agostino

Comment: sory i do all work u say but i cant do  open expelorer